# Default value of $#ArrayName when there is no element (Perl)

Tags: perl

The code below is to display the number of arguments entered in the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl –w
$myVar = $#ARGV + 1;
print "Hi " , $ARGV[0] , "\n";
print "You have $myVar arguments\n";
```

From the perlintro, `$#ARGV` is a special variable which tells you the index of the last element of an array.

If this is the case, when I don't enter any value in the command line, how does `$myVar` value end up with 0 ?

Is it because when there is no element in the array, the index of "no element" is -1 ? As -1 + 1 = 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$#ARGV` means "the index of the last element of ARGV" - not just any array as the perlintro sentence seems to imply.

For any array, if it's empty, `$#array` will be -1 and `scalar @array` will be 0.

CAVEAT: If someone has modified `$[` ("Index of first element"), that'll change `$#` as well.  You should *probably* always use `scalar @array` if you're after the length, and `$array[-1]` to get the last element.

```
> cat demo.pl
my @array = ();
print "Size=", scalar @array, " items, last=", $#array, "\n";
$[ = 2;
print "Size=", scalar @array, " items, last=", $#array, "\n";
> perl demo.pl
Size=0 items, last=-1
Size=0 items, last=1
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) page:

> @ARGV The array @ARGV contains the command-line arguments intended for
>   the script. $#ARGV is generally the number of arguments minus one,
>   because $ARGV[0] is the first argument, not the program's command name
>   itself. See $0 for the command name.

Answer (score 2):

You are right.

`$#ARGV` is `scalar @ARGV - 1`, as squiguy points out.

But there are less-noisier alternatives to count the number of arguments passed to your program that you should consider using instead:

```
my $count = scalar @ARGV;  # Explicit using of 'scalar' function
my $count = 0+@ARGV;       # Implicitly enforce scalar context
my $count = @ARGV;         # Since the context is already set by LHS
```

Comment: `$#ARGV` won't always be `scalar @ARGV-1` though.  `$#` is an unreliable mistress and should be treated as if there's a sharp axe in play.

Comment: @rjp : You're right that `$#ARGV == @ARGV - 1 + $[;`. The only thing stopping me from mentioning it is that `$[` was deprecated in 5.12. As it stands, I would venture to say that 99.9% of the time `$[ == 0`, if not more

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because when there is no element in the array, the index of "no element" is -1 ? As -1 + 1 = 0

Almost. It is not "the index of 'no element'" but rather the following rule applies:

[perldata](http://p3rl.org/perldata)

> The following is always true:
>
> scalar(@whatever) == $#whatever + 1;

Comment: That won't be true if some (evil) person has changed `$[`.